# In GWT, how to resize menu items so they stay confined to the menu bar

Tags: gwt, menuitem, menubar

In GWT, how do you prevent MenuItems from overflowing the bounds of a MenuBar with a preset pixel width?

I have tried changing the item's width with the setWidth method on the MenuItem object itself as well as on its associated Style object, but neither made a difference.

I also tried making the change to the MenuItem before and after they were added to the MenuBar.

Answer (score 0):

The MenuBar `private void openPopup(final MenuItem item) {...}` create a `DecoratedPopupPanel`. The popupPanel has a callback `popup.setPopupPositionAndShow(new PopupPanel.PositionCallback() {...}`. That is where the popUp position is calculated, if you can override this callback you can add your logic to test if it overflow and set the proper position. The problem is that the method is private, for a quick (and no so clean) solution I'd copy the whole class to another .java file and work using it as base for a new `MenuBar`.

Comment: Thanks Andre -- I guess there is no way to constrain the items to a preset MenuBar size using the given API?

Comment: I've read the MenuBar code, the PositionCallback just add itself relative the the parent and do not have and conditional except if it is vertical or horizontal MenuBar. Roll your sleeves and good luck :)

Comment: Looking at the source code, it looks like the openPopup method is for displaying a sub-menu attached to the MenuItem parameter.  In my code, I have a horizontal menu and the items themselves are what are overflowing -- is this related or is another approach required?

Comment: Can you attach a picture?

Comment: I don't have a high enough reputation to post pictures, but basically the menu bar is contained in a popup panel and adding too many items makes it overflow the panel.  I'd like to keep the panel size the same and just shrink the items to fit the preset width.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the question. After opening the menuItem I think you can iterate and calculate the width according.

Comment: I've tried setting the width of each item, calculated by taking the bar width and dividing by the number of items, before adding it to the bar and after but neither had an effect

Comment: You can set the width of the DecoratedPopupPanel, created when the MenuBar open the MenuItem at the method openPopup. That is why setting the width of the MenuItem doesn't work, you have to set the width of MenuItem container.

Comment: It seems like the DecoratedPopupPanel is only used for a sub-menu though.  The overflowing of the panel occurs even when I only have the horizontal MenuBar and several MenuItems attached to it (commands only - no sub-menus)